# Select row and display above

Tags: excel, vba

I want to display the selected row in a table in the top of the worksheet when the user clicks on any of the row's cells.

I am trying by using this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim myRowPos As Long
    Dim myRow As Range
    myRowPos = Selection.ListObject.Range.row
    Set myRow = ActiveCell.EntireRow 'I want to select the row in the table ONLY

    'Highlight the entire row here


Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
If IsEmpty(Target) Or Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveCell
    Range(Cells(.CurrentRegion.row, .Column), Cells(.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + .CurrentRegion.row - 1, .Column)).Interior.ColorIndex = 8
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    'Show above
    If Not myRow Is Nothing And myRowPos >= 9 Then
        Range("EditCountry").Value = myRow.Cells(1, 1)
        Range("EditNodeName").Value = myRow.Cells(1, 2)
        Range("EditNodeId").Value = myRow.Cells(1, 3)
        Range("EditParentNode").Value = myRow.Cells(1, 4)
        Range("EditParentNodeId").Value = myRow.Cells(1, 5)
        Range("EditActive").Value = myRow.Cells(1, 6)
        Range("EditFrom").Value = myRow.Cells(1, 7)
        Range("EditTo").Value = myRow.Cells(1, 8)
    End If

    'Save row in the table with the modified data when clicking a button

End Sub
```

My major problems are:
- I want to select the row IN THE TABLE ONLY (not the entire active row as apart from the table, the row contains other data...)
- Showing the row above and, if edited there, the info then edited in the row it was before (By clicking an Update button)

Comment: Why do you want the row to appear at the top? Simply to make it easier to edit somehow? Seems a bit extreme...

Comment: Yes, the table contains a lot of rows and I want to be able to edit only on the top (so that when clicking the update row button there are some checks performed). Thanks for the help! @jeffreyweir

Comment: Ah. Why not just leave the row in place and perform the checks there, and undo in need?

Comment: I think showing it above is more convenient, and my boss things the same hahaha... but thanks for challenging ;) @jeffreyweir

Answer (score 0):

`Worksheet_SelectionChange` fires on every single cursor move or mouse click. You can use `Intersect` to check whether a cell in the table is clicked. Put this to the top of the sub:

```
Dim rngTable as Range
Set rngTable = "B9:I349"    ' set a range var to the valid area of the table

If Intersect(rngTable, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
```

This does not prevent the sub from running but it will quickly exit in case. 
You can programmatically update rngTable as the table evolves.